# What are some options for trying my Javascript web app on my Android phone?

Tags: javascript

I am a new developer, and I am trying to build a geolocation tracking app using javascript, html5, and google maps. AS of now I have only that base of the project completed, location, mark, updates, and poly lines.  Also as far as I can tell the app seems to be working from the laptop. Before I go much further I want to to test the raw app on my phone to see if it really tracks my position. Is there a way to do this without uploading it to a server?  I already do have a site with hostgator.  What are my options?     Thank You

Comment: Just copy the files to the phone and open them locally in the phones browser. If the site does not work without access to its own web server, your do have to upload the file to the host and go from there.

Comment: Use an emulator on the PC

Comment: If you're in the same network, start a local server on your laptop and connect from your phone

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see this app in mobile's browser then you can set a firewall on your machine and using IP address you can access your app on mobile locally without any hosting such as HostGator.